# Error 403 google analytics API Access Not Configured

Tags: html, api

So, I am using gadash to get a google analytics dashboard on a system I am building. I had it working earlier with no problem but now It is throwing this 403 Access not configured error. Why would it do this with no code changes since it was working? It is being sent from a web server.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you exceeded the qouta allowed by Google. Or exceeded the requests per second limit.

403 means that the server understood the request but refuses to fulfill it.. And that the problem is not an  authentication problem as described [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

You can find [google analytics absolute limits here](http://www.customreportsharing.com/topic/53-what-are-the-absolute-limits-for-google-analytics/)

So please verify that the requests per seconds and quota didn't exceeds the Google limits.

Comment: the quota for Analytics API is 50k/day and Ive only made about 250 requests. Does the API Key need to be regenerated frequently or something like that expiring? The user has to authorize their account through their dashboard, they then enter their profile ID and we do a one time pull of the analytics data and display it. So it doesnt pull alot.